# Excel VBA: Row select with variables not working on merged cells, but does without variables

Tags: excel, vba

I have two macros that should do the same thing, but they don't. The recorded macro works correctly and is what I am trying to emulate, but for some reason when I add in my variables it doesn't work the same way.

This is the recorded macro:

```
Sub Macro8()
Rows("42:42").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
End Sub
```

This works correctly when I run it. When I have a merged cell from F30:F42, it inserts the row and the merged cell then goes from F30:F43.

This is my version:

```
Sub NewLine()

Dim NG As Long
Dim LRA As Long
LRA = 0

LRA = Range("C" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

NG = LRA + 13 ' The 13 rows here are where I would enter my findings in

Rows(NG & ":" & NG).Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

End Sub
```

NG = LRA + 13 correctly returns 42. The next line however selects rows 30 to 42, instead of just row 42. Because that line select 13 rows, it creates 13 rows on the next line of the macro.

Unless my use of (NG & ":" & NG) to replace ("42:42"), is incorrect, should it not do the same thing in both cases?

Thanks in advance for any input, this is driving me nuts.

Comment: I also tested both of your codes and they work just fine for me. I would still make the change I recommended in my answer. It is best to avoid `select` statements unless they are necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
Rows(NG & ":" & NG).Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

To:

```
Rows(NG).insert shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

`Rows` only needs 1 number in order for it to run, unless you have more than 1 row you are using.

Comment: Thank you Histerical! changing it to just Row(NG) fixed it. I also removed the .select like you suggested.